# How to make section fade on scroll?

Tags: javascript, scroll, fade

I am trying to make a section of my website fade out on scroll. I tried looking at other questions, but none helped. Here is the link to my code : http://bit.ly/1BmYnvo

Any help would be appreciated. If you could tell me why your code works, that would be great too!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your js, you're trying to select element(s) with `.social` class. The class is not set anywhere, therefore jQuery won't select any element, thus not changing opacity value on scroll.

**Fix**: add `class="social"` to your div.

```js
// As @Bojangles recommended, search for element only once to improve performace.
var $socialDiv = $('.social');
 
$(window).scroll(function() {
  //Get scroll position of window 
  var windowScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

  //Slow scroll of social div and fade it out 
  $socialDiv.css({
    'margin-top': -(windowScroll / 3) + "px",
    'opacity': 1 - (windowScroll / 550)
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="social">
  Hi!
</div>
```

Comment: You should move `var $socialDiv = $('.social')` outside the scroll handler to reduce the performance impact of querying the DOM every scroll event

Comment: I just copied the OP's code there, not modifying anything. Fixed it now.

Comment: Is there anyway you could make it fade out 100% only if it is at the bottom and fade out 0% if it is at the top using the same way shown? That would be great. I hope that makes sense...

Comment: Yes, replace your "magical height number" `550` with `Math.max($(document).height(), $(window).height())`.